# Cassandra CQLSH COPY FROM CSV: Can I create my own colum from others

Tags: csv, cassandra, copy, cqlsh

I often use the cqlsh command COPY...FROM CSV... but I have new needs.
I'd like to add an extra colum in my cassandra table that would be created from two other columns.

Example (cvs file)

```
1;2
2;4
3;6
```

would become a table with these values:

my table:    12;1;2
    24;2;4
    36;3;6

I ve used other options but they're much slower than COPY...FROM CSV

Do you know if I can do that using COPY...FROM CSV?

Comment: COPY command won't handle that operation. You can do data wrangling on the existing csv to create new columns. And then use the copy command.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with only copy command.

If you are using Linux then

First dumb the csv to file with copy command let's say `csv_test.csv`

```
1;2
2;4
3;6
```

Then use the below command to combine first two column into one.

```
cat csv_test.csv | awk -F ";" '{print $1$2 ";" $0}' > csv_test_combine.csv
```

Output file `csv_test_combine.csv` :

```
12;1;2
24;2;4
36;3;6
```